# Strange output from encoding chars

Tags: python, encryption

so i wrote this little script to encrypt a string given to and it works per se. however if certain characters are given, the output is getting weird and cant be returned correctly.

the code:

```
key = int(input("Encryption Key: "))
wordEnc = [0]*len(word)

for x in range(len(word)):
    letterKeyed = (ord(word[x]) + key)
    letterEnc = chr(letterKeyed)
    wordEnc[x] = letterEnc

print(wordEnc)

wordEnc = ''.join(wordEnc)
print(wordEnc)
```

output:

```
/usr/bin/python3.9 /run/media/endvour/CRACKY128GB/work/python/Encoder/encoder.py
Word to be encoded: qwertz
Encryption Key: 10
['{', '\x81', 'o', '|', '~', '\x84']
{o|~

Process finished with exit code 0
```

how can i solve this, so the output is readable?

Comment: When you add 10 to some character codes, you get the code for a control character. You need to decide how you want to deal with this. But if you do this, you might not be able to decode it, since two different characters might encode to the same thing.

Comment: in which way can i handle this?

Comment: In real world encryption, encrypted data is binary, and we use encoding like base64 to make it ordinary text.

Comment: since i jumped into this encryption thing with barely any information i though i could just change the character codes and that'd be it and didnt know of the existence of control characters. but i think base64 is exactly what i actually searched for. Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to do something like Caesar Cipher? It usually wraps around, so Z+10 is J

Comment: And non-letters are left alone.